# How do I push an element onto an array who's name is contained in a variable?

Tags: php, variable-variables

I'm making a generic php class which autoloads values into an object from a Database

To set properties I use this:

`$object->$propertyName = $valueFromDB;` where the value of propertyName is comes from the mysql field name..

Now I want to push something onto an array in a similar fashion:

This works..

`$object->$arryName = array();`

But this doesn't..

`$object->$arryName[] = "test";`

How can I work around this?

Comment: `arrayPush($object->$arryName, 'test')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$object->{$arryName}[] = "test"
```

The curly braces change the order of operations and will make PHP evaluate the variable name before the hard braces.

If you want to do a associative array, this gets a little more complicated:

```
$object->{$arryName}[$keyname] = "test"
```

In this case, you *can* put curly braces around $keyname but it's entirely optional.

On a related note.. variable variables are usually - *but not always* - a sign of something screwy. They're also a pain to whoever is coming after you who has to debug, refactor, do any grepping, etc. If you *must* use them, fine but make sure you've considered the ramifications.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.. instead of using variable variables for the task I'm doing (auto loading a model class with its mysql DB fields) is there any other way you would suggest doing it?

Comment: I think that's about the only reasonable time.. though be careful with auto-assignment. Make sure that *you* define the fields that are being auto-assigned and not the user such as if you get name/value pairs from a form submission. If you have a property called 'isAdmin' and a user submits isAdmin=true then they can make your life.. challenging. It's basically register_globals all over again.